# Error While running Simple console application as Azure webjob

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I created a simple console application and runing it as Azure webjob, getting below error. Same code working fine in local.

> [10/10/2016 18:15:48 > 494acb: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:48 > 494acb: SYS INFO] Run script 'ConsoleApplication1.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:48 > 494acb: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:49 > 494acb: ERR ] 
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:49 > 494acb: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:49 > 494acb: ERR ]    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:49 > 494acb: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:49 > 494acb: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:49 > 494acb: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:49 > 494acb: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation.Execute(CloudTableClient client, CloudTable table, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:49 > 494acb: ERR ]    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.Execute(TableOperation operation, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:49 > 494acb: ERR ]    at ConsoleApplication1.Program.getStockPriceFromGoogle()
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:49 > 494acb: ERR ]    at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:49 > 494acb: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
>   [10/10/2016 18:15:49 > 494acb: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766

Console App code :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        getStockPriceFromGoogle();
    }

    public static void getStockPriceFromGoogle()
    {

        try
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAcount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAcount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable googleStockTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("GoogleStock");
            googleStockTable.CreateIfNotExists();

            const string tickers = "RELIANCE,SBIN";
            string json = null;

            try
            {
                using (var web = new WebClient())
                {
                    var url = $"http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE%3A{tickers}";
                    json = web.DownloadString(url);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Error calling Google service , error :" + ex.ToString());
            }

            //Google adds a comment before the json for some unknown reason, so we need to remove it
            json = json.Replace("//", "");

            var v = JArray.Parse(json);

            foreach (var i in v)
            {
                var ticker = i.SelectToken("t");
                var price = (decimal)i.SelectToken("l");

                GoogleStock googleStock = new GoogleStock(ticker.ToString(), DateTime.Now)
                {
                    Price = price,
                    PriceInLocalCurrency = i.SelectToken("l_cur").ToString(),

                    id = (int)i.SelectToken("id"),
                    Exchange = i.SelectToken("e").ToString(),
                    Chanage = (float)i.SelectToken("c"),
                    ChnagePersontage = (float)i.SelectToken("cp"),
                    LastTradeTime = (DateTime)i.SelectToken("lt_dts"),

                };

                try
                {
                    TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(googleStock);
                    googleStockTable.Execute(insertOperation);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine("Error When saving data , error :" + ex.ToString());
                    throw;
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"{ticker} : {price}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Error When saving data , error :" + ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
}

class GoogleStock : TableEntity
{
    public GoogleStock(string StockName, DateTime InsertionDate)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = StockName;
        this.RowKey = InsertionDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }

    public string StockName { get; set; }

    public string Exchange { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string PriceInLocalCurrency { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastTradeTime { get; set; }

    public float Chanage { get; set; }

    public float ChnagePersontage { get; set; }
}
```

I added app setting key in azure portal , still no help.

Comment: Looks like you're getting a storage exception. First step is isolate to a simpler scenario that doesn't involve WebJobs, per [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Isolating-WebJobs-and-Deployment-script-issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many [factors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179438.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) could cause 400 bad request error when we do an operation on the Table service. For example, the property name is invalid, the value specified is invalid etc.

> Same code working fine in local.

I test your code on my local, your code do not work (it returns 400 bad request error) on my local. I find that you use a datetime-based row key(`this.RowKey = InsertionDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString();`), which may cause this type issue. The row key value looks like **10/11/2016 3:14:03 AM** (having the forward slash (/) character) on my local. However the forward slash (/) character is not allowed in values for the PartitionKey and RowKey properties. Please check “[Characters Disallowed in Key Fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)” section.

You could try to use the following code taking the current time value in Ticks as the Row Key value.

```
this.RowKey = InsertionDate.Ticks.ToString("d19");
```

Besides, you could check [this article](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/using-time-based-partition-keys-in-azure-table-storage/) which explained two approaches to generate a Partition Keys based on datetime.

Comment: Thanks It worked, I used ToFileTimeUtc  "InsertionDate.ToFileTimeUtc().ToString();" .  Just for information  the above was working in my local , and it's value coming like this '10-10-2016 15:27:03' , i think "-" is valid character .